# Reading raw byte data in C++

Tags: c++, c

I have a really basic question. I want to turn an LED on/off depending on the BLE data received by a Nrf52 BLE device. My problem is that the data (Received_Data) is in raw bytes data form (1 byte), and I don't know how to perform an if statement on that, or convert it into a form that can.
In the code below I have:

```
                if (Received_Data > 50)
                    {
                      nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_2);
                    }
                 end
```

How can I let 'Received_Data' be used in an IF statement like this, so it can be read as an integer or a hex number?

```
        case APP_UART_DATA_READY:
        UNUSED_VARIABLE(app_uart_get(&data_array[index]));
        index++;

        if ((data_array[index - 1] == '\n') ||
            (data_array[index - 1] == '\r') ||
            (index >= m_ble_nus_max_data_len))
        {
            if (index > 1)
            {
                NRF_LOG_DEBUG("Ready to send data over BLE NUS");
                NRF_LOG_HEXDUMP_DEBUG(Received_Data, index);

                 if (Received_Data > 50)
                    {
                      nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_2);
                    }
                 end
```

This is doing my head in. I'm sure this can be answered by someone in 5 seconds. and I am beyond the point where I can invest the time to dig through all the associated C++ documentation to find the solution.

Comment: See `uint8` data type.

Comment: @Thomas Nitpick: The standard type is `uint8_t`.

Comment: Try `if (Received_Data & LED_2)`, if `LED_2` is a bit within the byte.

Comment: There's [std::byte](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) for representing raw bytes.

Comment: How is `Received_Data` defined?

Comment: It is already defined as a uint8: uint8_t Received_Data[BLE_NUS_MAX_DATA_LEN];

Comment: That's an array of bytes, not a single byte. What do you want to do with it, exactly? Check that the first byte in the array is 50?

Comment: Just want to check that the byte within the array is above or below a certain threshold, such as 50. What would be the syntax to do that with an IF statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question

> How can I let 'Received_Data' be used in an IF statement like this, so
>   it can be read as an integer or a hex number?

From your comments

> It is already defined as a uint8: uint8_t
>   Received_Data[BLE_NUS_MAX_DATA_LEN];
>
> Just want to check that the byte within the array is above or below a
>   certain threshold, such as 50. What would be the syntax to do that
>   with an IF statement?

`Received_Data` is an array of unsigned 8-bit integers. In the first piece of code you provided:

```
if (Received_Data > 50){
    nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_2);
}
```

`Received_Data` decays to a pointer to the first element of the array. Therefore, you are actually comparing between a pointer and an integer (which is expressly forbidden by ISO C++). If you want to check the value of a specific element of that array, then you need to index it with the subscript operator like so:

```
//byte_of_interest is some non-negative integer value that specifically represents
//the element in the array that you are interested in comparing with 50
if (Received_Data[byte_of_interest] > 50){
    nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_2);
}
```

Likewise, you can also use pointer arithmetic:

```
//byte_of_interest is an offset from the beginning of the array
//so its contents are located at the address to the beginning of the array + the offset
if (*(Received_Data + byte_of_interest) > 50){
    nrf_gpio_pin_toggle(LED_2);
}
```

Furthermore, I recommend that you initialize the array to 0 to prevent getting false positives before the array is filled in (e.g. `uint8_t Received_Data[BLE_NUS_MAX_DATA_LEN] = {0};`)

Answer (score 0):

Since Received_Data is an uint8_t array, you can access individual bytes directly:

```
if (Received_Data[0] > 50)
//or
if (Received_Data[index] > 50)
```

uint8_t is [0..255].